# Deserialization of object in Class Library while accepting an interface parameter (C#, MVC)

Tags: c#, json, interface, json.net, deserialization

Given the interface:

```
interface IObject
{
   public string Name {get;set}   
}
```

And the following objects:

```
class A: IObject
{
   public string Name {get;set}
   public int ID {get;set;}
}

class B: IObject
{
   public string Name {get;set}
   public Guid ID {get;set;}
}
```

I have two consuming applications which are using different database schemae, but do the same job.  This is a matter of maintaining an old app while a team writes a new one.  Requirements include that both use the same library, which is why this problem exists. The apps both call the same external API, and that call is in its own static class and is accessed like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<IObject> List(Guid listUniqueIdentifier)
 {
       //a custom class to call the API
       using (var cmd = new WebApiCommand()) 
       {
                               //custom enum
             cmd.CommandType = ApiComType.GET;
             cmd.Command = "ListObjects";
             cmd.Filter = listUniqueIdentifier.ToString();
             IEnumerable<object> data = cmd.Execute();
             var result = new List<IObject>();
             foreach(var d in data)
             {
               result.add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IObject>(Convert.ToString(d)));
             }
             return result;
       }   

}
```

Obviously, you can't instantiate an interface, so

```
result.add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IObject>(Convert.ToString(d)));
```

breaks. I don't want to just attempt to construct the GUID-using version and if it fails, use the integer version.  Not only is that a little hacky, but it's the newer DB that is using the integer, so I'd be using a `try` block as flow control in just about the worse possible way.  How can I deserialize to the right object instance type (A or B) without writing different methods for each type?  Edit: The solutions I've found usually involve either serializing the $type or otherwise saving the instance type during serialization.  That is not possible, as the API is connected to a third party application and cannot store this datum.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to detect the type of ID and then instantiate and populate the correct type of object during deserialization:

```
class CustomIObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(IObject).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        IObject target;
        if (jo["ID"].Type == JTokenType.Integer)
        {
            target = Activator.CreateInstance<A>();
        }
        else  // Guid
        {
            target = Activator.CreateInstance<B>();
        }
        serializer.Populate(jo.CreateReader(), target);
        return target;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, just pass an instance of it to `DeserializeObject()`:

```
var converter = new CustomIObjectConverter();
...
foreach(var d in data)
{
    result.add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IObject>(Convert.ToString(d), converter));
}
```

Here is a short demo to prove the concept: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p2HzsL

Answer (score 0):

Your issue, as far as I can tell, is that you have no way to identify, by "d" which type of class to serialize into.
(Pseudo)

```
foreach(var d in data)
    {
       like if(Convert.ToString(d).All(char.IsDigit) && Convert.ToString(d).length <= Int32.MaxValue)
       {
          result.add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(Convert.ToString(d)));
       }
       else
       {
          result.add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(Convert.ToString(d)));
       }

    }
```

EDIT: I think this is the best approach with the limited info you have given. If not, I would recommend, that you alter the data call itself, so the WebAPI can provide you with two different sets of data depending on the calling application if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

One approach I can think of, is to add an internal helper class that you deserialize to first and from there generate your `A` and `B` objects.  Something like this (Note: I am assuming your GUID is without a separator character).

```
internal class Helper
{
    public string _name {get;set;}
    public string _id {get;set;}

    public IObject GetAOrBObject()
    {
        if (_id.Length == 32) // Assume GUID with no separator like '-'
        {
            return new A() { Name = _name, ID = Guid.Parse(_id) };
        }
        else
        {
            return new B() { Name = _name, ID = int.Parse(_id) };
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can change the code in your loop to this:

```
foreach(var d in data)
{
    var temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Helper>(Convert.ToString(d)));
    result.add(temp.GetAOrBObject());
}
return result;
```